# Will it be good to use branding TEXT at the start of Meta description?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, meta-description, ctr

- Will it be good to use branding TEXT at the start of Meta
  description?
- Will it harm in anyways if I use it in all my pages?

[image]

Check out the green box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three basic rules for writing meta descriptions:

- Use a meta description that is likely to lead to higher click-through rates. Do you think that your brand name will make a user more likely to click on your listing? If so, use it. If not, don't use it.
- Don't use duplicate meta descriptions. Don't use a meta description at all if you can't think of an original description to use.
- Write meta descriptions for humans. i.e. Don't spam keyphrases and keywords, as Google does not use the meta description as a ranking factor.

Comment: Do you think having my company name with TM before the meta description in all pages would be consider duplicate?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think the most important question is: What is the benefit of adding it in the first place? Your meta description should entice people to click on the result for your website. Adding a brand name at the start isn't really a great way to achieve this, unless your brand is really well known.

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing meta title and meta description with keywords is always a great idea because they get crawled  first in the site. But there are few things that you need to take into consideration:

1. Do not stuff your keywords
2. Use brand name in different forms, for example if you are having your brand name "mysweethouse", then you can use: mysweethouse, mysweet house, my sweet house, my sweethouse etc.
3. Be in the word limit of meta description.

Comment: Keyword manipulation has not disappeared entirely, however, this advice is sounding a bit old-school though not incorrect. Search will do search term matches against the title tag and description meta-tag, however, the description meta-tag terms are not weighted like they are in title tags. Title tags and description meta-tags should contain terms you want to be found by, but written for humans and proper SERP CTR.

Comment: @vinay aggarwal  Thanks for answering, however, here my aim is to create an attraction in a form of my brand name with a TM so as to get even a slight edge on my competitors. I wont be stuffing, except I want to start my all meta description with my Brand Name as in the image. Will it help? Or will it fire back in form of google penalty or It would be considered partially duplicate ? Any inputs, suggestions or advice?